# SQL Server Join two tables, incorrect sum in the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting incorrect result when join two tables. The Runlog.casecount gets multiply by the number of records on the second table (Vppallets) that contains the same palletid number, but it has duplicates palletid on it (on purpose) but the result I get it is not the correct one. Right now I'm using the where clause in my query but I also get the same incorrect result.

Expected result

```
RunID   Cases    vpLot
----------------------
1872    104.00   136
1872    104.00   137
```

Current result with current code:

```
RunID   Cases    vpLot
-----------------------
1872    312.00   136
1872    312.00   137
```

Current query

```sql
SELECT   
    Vppallets.RunID, 
    SUM(RunLog.casecount) AS Cases,
    Vppallets.vplot
FROM
    Vppallets, RunLog
WHERE
    Vppallets.vpPalletID = RunLog.PalletID
    AND Vppallets.RunID = 1872
GROUP BY 
    Vppallets.RunID, Vppallets.vplot
```

Sample data below:

**Vppallets**

```
vpPalletID  PalletNumber    RunID   casecount   vplot
-----------------------------------------------------
5000120     4001810         1872    34.66       136
5000120     3001802         1872    34.66       136
5000120     3001856         1872    34.66       136
5000123     4001808         1872    34.66       137
5000123     3001801         1872    34.66       137
5000123     4001833         1872    34.66       137
```

**Runlog**

```
RunID   PalletID    casecount
-----------------------------
1872    5000120     104.00
1872    5000123     104.00
```

I know where the duplicate comes from in the where, I have also tried doing join, also duplicates I get the exact same result, and if I remove the conditions, then the results, it's even worst.

Comment: Is Vppallets a view?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RunID, vpPalletID, vplot
    FROM Vppallets
    WHERE RunID = 1872
)
SELECT CTE.RunID, SUM(RL.casecount) AS Cases, CTE.vplot
FROM CTE INNER JOIN RunLog RL ON CTE.vpPalletID = RL.PalletID
GROUP BY CTE.RunID, CTE.vplot
```

[image]

Comment: @Juan G, yes I forgot that one. Edited is my query using some table variables.